# Vertically align text that is inside a select element for IE8

Tags: select, internet-explorer-8, input, vertical-alignment

I have an HTML input element of type select. The height of the element is 28px. Without modifying the element with CSS, the text inside gets automatically vertically-aligned in all browsers except for IE8. In IE8 the select's text is in the bottom left corner of the element.

Does anyone know how to vertically-align the text inside an HTML select element?

Comment: What code are you using to accomplish this?

Comment: I want to do this is in just HTML and CSS

Comment: I'm aware - could you post the code you've used so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without your `html` it is hard to know exactly what you are styling. It sounds like you are using something like `<input type="select" />` but that isn't actually valid html.

However, to vertically align the text in the middle you need to set the `line-height` to be the same figure as your `height`.

So in this case you would need to set **`line-height: 28px;`** to match `height: 28px;`.

For your `html` I would recommend either using:

- `<input type="text" />` if you are looking for a standard text input

  or
- If you are looking for a drop down selection:

  ```
  <select>
      <option value="Test1">Test 1</option>
      <option value="Test2">Test 2</option>
  </select>
  ```

Comment: Good stuff. For whatever reason, when you change the height of an `input`, latest Firefox and Chrome correctly re-set the line height, and IE9 treats it this way as well, but IE 8 and 7 do not automatically set the line-height as such. This helps. Thanks!

Comment: Setting line-height to match height didn't help me. :(